# PowerMock error with hibernate validator (JSR - 303)

Tags: java, junit, bean-validation, powermock

We are using powermock for mocking static methods. Our code seems as follows

```
public class ValidationLayer{
    private GenericInputValidator v;
    public ValidationLayer(GenericValidator v){
       this.v = v;
    }
    public boolean isValid(MyObject obj){
       Logger.info(MyFinalClass.staticMethod());
       return v.validate();
    }
}

public class GenericInputValidator{
   private MyOwnValidator validator;
   //setters & getters
   public boolean validate(Object toBeValidated){
      validator.validate(toBeValidated);
   }
}

public class MyOwnValidator(){
   private Validator v;
   public MyOwnValidator(){
     v = Validation.byProvider(HibernateValidator.class).configure()
         .buildValidationFactory().getValidator();
   }
   public validate(){
      //this calls validator method of javax.validation.Validate and analyzes 
      //the result and returns true or false based on the case.
   }
}

My test class looks like following where MyBean annotated with proper JSR-303 annotations

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyFinalClass.class})
public TestClass{
  @Test
  public void testValidationLayer(MyBean bean){
      PowerMock.mockStatic(MyFinalClass.class);
      EasyMock.expect(MyFinalClass.staticMethod()).andReturn("dummy data");
      GenericInputValidator v = new GenericInputValidator(new MyOwnValidator());
      ValidationLayer vLayer = new ValidationLayer(v);
      vLayer.isValid()
  }

}
```

Then while running tests it is showing the following error

```
javax.validation.ValidationException : Unable to get available provider resolvers
javax.validation.Validation$ProviderSpecificBootstrapImpl.configure()
```

On digging deep I understood that configure() is causing problem which is throwing exception
when it is unable to find the provide resolvers(I saw the exception throwing with this message
in source code ).I don't know why it is saying like that even when I am providing HibernateValidator.class.

More weird thing is if I didn't use powermock to mock static methods i.e., if I remove my Logger
code, then everything is working fine.

Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: What is the full stack trace? So you are having Hibernate Validator on the classpath as well?

Comment: Yes I have . Funny thing here is application is running fine with hibernate validator but tests fail . Previously when I didn't use that static method tests ran successfully Injecting powermock just to mock that static method ruined the things.

Comment: The tests for methods (methods which calls validation) which doesn't use powermock are getting passed. But once I added that static method I started using powermock which is the problem in my case, I guess.

Comment: The stack trace is exactly as shown [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/dropwizard-user/JnQKNh8jZMU/m7RTGs6J9-YJ)

Answer (score 0):

Check the PowerMockIgnore annotation. It allows you to configure which classes (eg: "javax.*") will not be substituted by mocks.