# Mocking method calls of unknown instances in easymock

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, easymock

I have a class with a method like this

```
class MyClass(){
   public String myMethod(){
       Logger.info(new MyOtherClass().myOtherMethod());
   }
}
```

> How can I mock the call of myOtherMethod() with EasyMock?

Background :

> Initially I wrote myOtherMethod as static method. For testing, as I cannot mock static method calls
>   I ended up writing an instance method which calls static method.
> I tried mocking the static method versin of my code with PowerMock, but it is showing some errors while working with JSR-303 bean validators (please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307632/powermock-error-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303)) and also I didn't find any working solution for integrating PowerMockRunner with SpringJunit4ClassRunner which is one of my case.

Comment: I don't think you can with Easymock. Try Powermock.

Comment: You cannot mock this call with EasyMock because you cannot mock the MyOtherClass object.

Comment: Whether you mock a static method, or mock a constructor, you'll need to use PowerMock. The main error people make is including the incorrect classes in the @PrepareForTest annotations. The documentation for how to mock statics and constructors is actually pretty good. [Here's The mocking statics one](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) and [here's the mocking constructors one](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor)

Comment: Instance method is getting mocked with powermock. But, I am getting the same exception as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25307632/powermock-error-with-hibernate-validator-jsr-303)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PowerMock.expectNew(...)` mocking functionality as described [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor).

Make sure you have annotated the test case class correctly. Many times folks miss out on the detail that you have to use the class invoking the constructor in the `@PrepareForTest(ClassThatCreatesTheNewInstance.class)` annotation.

If you still face error, please post your Test case code and stack trace.